# Can't install Yesod on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, yesod

I just tried to install Yesod on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise 32) on a Vagrant box.

Install of Haskell Platform was ok.

Then : "cabal install yesod-platform --force-reinstalls"

caused a fail with :

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
vault-0.3.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
wai-1.4.0.2 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
wai-app-static-1.3.1.4 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
wai-extra-1.3.4.4 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
wai-logger-0.3.1 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
wai-test-1.3.1.1 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
warp-1.3.9.2 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-1.2.2.1 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-auth-1.2.2.1 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-core-1.2.4.2 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-form-1.3.2.1 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-persistent-1.2.1 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-platform-1.2.4.2 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-static-1.2.0.1 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-test-1.2.1 depends on vault-0.3.0.1 which failed to install.
```

Which I guess means vault is not found. I have no understanding of what is afoot here, what this package is and why it has failed to install on a brand new fresh Ubuntu box with a brand new Haskell platform

All pointers gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: Give it a try with `cabal-dev install yesod-platform` in the directory of your project.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand 'in the directory of my project'. I haven't got a project yet because I haven't installed yesod??

Comment: Well, you install it because you want to work on a project involving it, right?

Comment: You are using cabal to install the yesod dependencies globally, but something is conflicting with something in the haskell platform, so Mihia is saying install the dependencies at the project level by using cabal dev in a new folder you create for your project.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the more recent version of `vault` on Hackage is broken. You can work around this by telling `cabal` to install an older version:

```
cabal install yesod-platform --force-reinstalls --constraint 'vault < 0.3.0.1'
```

I'll file a bug report against vault about this.

Comment: It compiles fine if you clone the repo. Not a great solution, but it gets you around the problem for now.

Comment: thanks Michael - that works, now have another problem I don't understand... posted as a separate question.

Comment: FYI, it looks like a patched vault has been uploaded, so the constraint should no longer be necessary.